# Selenium + Python: InvalidSelectorException for an xpath locator

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm using Pycharm with my Python auto-tests for single-page-application where I have a users page, where there's a users block with some input fields.
So one of the fields' html code is:

```
<div data-v-1f9916c7="" class="el-input">
```

When I use a pycharm python console with executed geckodriver window to debug some things, I write: `wd.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[4]").send_keys("123456")` and everything works - I see a numbers in needed input field.
Then I go back to my auto-tests code where we use PageObject with locators, and my locator looks like that: `NAME = (By.XPATH,"(//input[@type='text'])[4]")` and a class method looks like that:

```
class UsersPage(BasePage):
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.driver.find_element(*UsersPageLocators.NAME).send_keys(name)
```

And then I run my tests (in PyCharm also) and get an error: `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//input[@type='text'])[4]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.`
HTML code for that element has nothing special:

```html
<div data-v-1f9916c7="" class="el-input">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="el-input__inner">
</div>
```

Please help me to understand why is that xpath locator is valid in python console and invalid in tests itself? Maybe because of different type of using "by": `find_element_by_xpath` and `By.XPATH`?

Comment: `//input[@type='text'])[4]` The error is probably the unmatched `)`.

Comment: OHHH. You're so right! I'm really sorry for my inattention!

Comment: By the way, after fixing the unmatched `)` I got another error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@type='text'][4]` which is way more strange

Comment: Why is that strange?  How many `<input type="text">` elements are on the page?

Comment: There can be multiple element with the attribute `type="text"` on the same page So customize your xpath and make it unique. lets say `//input@type='text'][@class='el-input__inner']`  else you have to pick parent element surrounding.

Comment: @JohnGordon A lot, 16.

Comment: @NarendraR Since there are 16 inputs on the page, I had to try to add an index number at the end. Thank you for an advice, I will try it!